# npm install "Adding a cache directory" error on windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm

After updating **Node.js** to `0.10.23`, I'm having an error when trying to install grunt:
`npm install -g grunt-cli`.

System: Win7 x64. Node version: 0.10.23, npm ver: 1.3.17

```
66 silly lockFile d63f3d0b-grunt-cli grunt-cli@
67 error Error: Adding a cache directory to the cache will make the world implode.
67 error     at addLocalDirectory (c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:1120:45)
67 error     at c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:1173:7
67 error     at cb (c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\tar.js:150:7)
67 error     at c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\tar.js:147:9
67 error     at c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\lockfile\lockfile.js:61:41
67 error     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
68 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
68 error including the npm and node versions, at:
68 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
69 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
70 error command "c:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
71 error cwd z:\home\minpik.lc\www
72 error node -v v0.10.23
73 error npm -v 1.3.17
74 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thx, all. Looks like node.js 0.10.23 buged thing. I have totally removed latest version and installed 0.8.9, Now it's ok.

Comment: You need to remove earlier version of node completely before upgrading version in node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue, it looks like it's only version 0.10.23 that's the problem. I installed 0.10.22 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to completely remove the earlier version of node before upgrading node version. If you want to switch between different versions of node, use [Node version manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

To upgrade to node version 0.10 using nvm,

```
nvm install 0.10
```

To use older version of Node (say 0.8)

```
nvm use 0.8
```

I find nvm really useful tool to toggle between different node versions. Try it!! **NVM is only for linux enviroments.**

**For windows**, you can use either [NVMW](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw). See this [BLOG](http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2013/03/23/installing-and-switching-between-multiple-versions-of-node-js-n-vs-nvm/) for a good help.

Comment: problem was in node.js version. And NVM is really interesting thing, i'll try it on ubuntu, thx.

Comment: It works like charm on ubuntu..I use it like almost everytime when I need to fix a cross-version bug..If you can develop on linux, I suggest you to always use linux instead of windows

Comment: Can't npm install nvmw because of the cache error :)  Irony at its best.